# Как в регулярках выводить только числа? JS

Tags: регулярные-выражения

Нужно выводить только числа и числа с плавающей точкой. Выводит это, но не корректным образом - ["123", "56K7", "3,4", "76", "9,7,", "9.0float"];
Как избавится от 56K7, 9,7, и 9.0float -ибо это не числа, или числа которые неправильно записаны.

```
function getNumbersWithFloat(value){
  const arrayOfIndex = value.split(' ');
  const lenValue = arrayOfIndex.length;
  const regExp = /^([0-9]+(\.|\,)+[0-9])|[0-9]$/;
  let arrayResult = [];
  for(var j=0; j<lenValue; j++){ 
     const match = regExp.exec(arrayOfIndex[j]);
     if(match != null){
      arrayResult.push(arrayOfIndex[j]);
      console.log(arrayResult);
      }
  }
}
getNumbersWithFloat('string and num 123 and 56K7 3,4 76 9,7, 9.0float');
```

Comment: Я так понимаю, речь о JS?

Comment: да, const regExp = /^([0-9]+(\.|\,)+[0-9])$|[0-9]$/; вот так получается  все что после числа убирается, но все что внутри числа- воспринимается как число - то есть, 34шГ8 - это число..

Comment: ` /^([0-9]+(\.|\,)+[0-9])|[0-9]$/gi` попробуйте поставить эти 2 флага.

Comment: числа внутри все равно воспринимаются.

Comment: `^(\d+(?:[.,]\d+)?)$`

Comment: nope - не работает.

Comment: Вы реально , прям так вставили? я слеши потерял =))) А вы даже не подумали и вставили, что-то у меня все работает. И получается массив: `["123", "3,4", "76"]`

Comment: и правда, я выделила всю регулярку и заместила вашим примером. it's work! что делает - вот эти символы вместе ?:

Comment: Это **Группировка без обратной связи** Вот [тут](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A0%D0%B5%D0%B3%D1%83%D0%BB%D1%8F%D1%80%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B5_%D0%B2%D1%8B%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F) описано более подробно Советую почитать.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Больше ничего не стал менять в вашем примере.

```
function getNumbersWithFloat(value){
  const arrayOfIndex = value.split(' ');
  const lenValue = arrayOfIndex.length;
  const regExp = /^(\d+(?:[.,]\d+)?)$/;
  let arrayResult = [];
  for(var j=0; j<lenValue; j++){ 
     const match = regExp.exec(arrayOfIndex[j]);
     if(match != null){
      arrayResult.push(arrayOfIndex[j]);
      console.log(arrayResult);
      }
  }
}
getNumbersWithFloat('string and num 123 and 56K7 3,4 76 9,7, 9.0float');
```

Answer (score 0):

Ну вот так работает, кажется.

```js
let str = 'string and num 123 and 56K7 3,4 76 9,7, 9.0float';
let strArr = str.split(' ');
let resArr = [];
let reg = /[A-Za-z]|,$/;

for(let word of strArr) {
  if(!reg.test(word)) {
    resArr.push(word);
  }
}
for(let n of resArr) {
  console.log(n);
}
```

Comment: Наберите `3+4 ` и увидите число `3+4`, а также с другими символьными типами в целом. Хоть так: `3^4 3#3` и т. д...